# Proving $\bigcap_n I_n \neq \emptyset$ for monotonically smaller closed intervals $(I_n)_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

**Theorem:** Let $(I_n)_n$ be monotonically smaller closed intervals. i.e. $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$
Then $$\bigcap_n I_n \neq \emptyset$$
I easily grasped this geometrically, But I doubt of my proof. This is my proof:

---

Since $I_n$'s are real closed intervals, $I_n \neq \emptyset$. Then we can take $x \in I_n$. Since $I_n\subseteq I_{n-1}$, $x \in I_{n-1}$.
And generally from that,
$$x \in I_{n-2} \Rightarrow x \in I_{n-3} \Rightarrow x \in I_{n-4} \Rightarrow...\Rightarrow x \in I_2 \Rightarrow x \in I_1$$

Thus $x \in I_{n}$ is also in other closed intervals $I_i$s where $i < n-1$. Thus,
$$\bigcap_{i \leq n} I_i \neq \emptyset$$ Then, if we just take $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ equation will still hold and consequently,
$$\bigcap_{n} I_n \neq \emptyset$$

---

To me, it looks right, but I could'nt be sure. I would appreciate your short-time look. Thanks from now.

Comment: How would you prove uniqueness in this way?

Comment: It is necessary to assume that $I_n\ne \emptyset, \forall n.$ Note that $\emptyset$ is a closed set.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not think that the ``$\lim_{n \to \infty}$''-argument in the very end is valid. Maybe you can instead construct a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of real numbers such that $x_n \in I_n$ for every $n$, with the property that $(x_n)_n$ converges and $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \in \bigcap_n I_n$.

Comment: @mfl $\emptyset$ is a closed set, but it is not a closed interval.

Comment: @5xum: Isn't $[a,b] = \emptyset$ if $a > b$?

Comment: @mfl it popped out in my mind but because writer does not note that I falsily though that empty set is not a closed set. If it is a closed set yes you are right, we have to assume $I_n \neq \emptyset$

Comment: @Algebrus, don't be sorry. It is the part that most confuses me. It did not entirely satisfy me. I will try and see what you said.

Comment: @Algebrus In most textbooks, a closed interval is defined as $[a,b]$ where $a\leq b$.

Comment: Statement of theorem should include that the intervals are also bounded. For instance the nested sequence $I_n=[n,\infty)$ has empty intersection.

Comment: @Bora - Everyone agrees that the empty set is closed. This is a basic definition of topology. However, there is (as you see here) some disagreement over whether it should be considered an *interval*. paw88789 is correct that you need the intervals (at least one of them) to be bounded. This result is a property of compactness, not closedness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then, if we just take $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ equation will still hold
> and consequently, $$\bigcap_{n} I_n \neq \emptyset$$

This is bad reasoning. Just because some relation holds for all values of $n$, that does **not** mean the relation holds for the limit.

For example, the relation $\frac1n > 0$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$, but the relation $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n > 0$$

does **not** hold.

---

Another way to see your proof is not OK is this:

If $I_n$ are **open** intervals, then your "proof" can be used to prove that $$\bigcap_n I_n \neq \emptyset$$

even though it is possbile to find a sequence of intervals such that their intersection is empty (for example, $I_n = (0, 10^{-n})$).

---

To improve your proof: well, it's not really a case of improving it, I'm afraid your best bet is to go back to the drawing board. Try to find a value $x$ that is in **all** intervals $I_n$. To find it, think about $I_n=[a_n, b_n]$, and then think about the sequences $a_1, a_2,\dots$ and $[b_1, b_2, \dots]$. What are some of their interesting properties?

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid my conclusion at the end also. But I now fathomed that why it may be wrong, I will try what you've said. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For the case $I_n=[0,1/n]$ the number $1/100$
belongs to $I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_{100}$ but not to $I_{101}$

Hint: Use Bolzano-Weierstrass.